# When using Latex - documentclass{exam} how do I precede the question number with a word? (I would like the word question to be there)

Tags: exam

```
\documentclass{exam} 

\begin{document} 
\bf {This is easy enough}
\begin{questions}
\question What is the sum of 1 and 1
\end{questions}
\vspace{2cm}
But what I really want is :\\\\
Question 1. What is the sum of 1 and 1

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question,  but you shouldn't use two letter font commands like \bf this millennium, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{exam} 

\renewcommand\questionlabel{Question \thequestion.}

\begin{document} 
\textbf{This is easy enough}
\begin{questions}
\question What is the sum of 1 and 1
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - I have much to learn - this time I learnt two things for the price of a single question.!

Comment: @GaryHoran You're welcome!

Comment: @GaryHoran In Germany, we have a saying which goes along the lines of "All good things come in groups of three", so here is the third tiny bit to learn: Don't use `\\ ` for linebreaks. They should only be used in tables and similar environment.  Instead just leave an empty line in the source to start a new paragraph.

Comment: See also \vspace, \smallsekip, \medskip and \bigskip.